# Angularjs ajax being called mulitple time when swtiching views using $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, ajax, route-provider

I am getting multiple calls to the same ajax function call when I switch views from the navigation. Say I'm on the Residents.html, the ajax will trigger off just once (normally). 
POST localhost:64752/api/Residents/GetResidents

Now if I navigate to the Home.html and navigate back to the Residnets.html per navigation click it gets trigger twice.
localhost:64752/api/Residents/GetResidents
localhost:64752/api/Residents/GetResidents

Now if I navigate to the Home.html again and navigate back to the Residents.html it gets triggered 3 times.
localhost:64752/api/Residents/GetResidents
localhost:64752/api/Residents/GetResidents
localhost:64752/api/Residents/GetResidents

The more you navigate from page to page the number of calls are increasing.
The views or .html pages do not contain the Controller ng-controller so that's clear.

All the ajax calls are coming for the controllers, and I have some directives that I have created that use ajax calls as well.

// app.js
var app = angular.module("apartment", ["ngRoute", "ngResource", "apartment.homeController","apartment.apartmentsController","apartment.residentsController", "ngResource"]);

```
// Config...
app.config(function ($routeProvider) { 

    $routeProvider
       .when("/", {
           templateUrl: "View/home.html",
           controller: "homeController",
       })
        .when("/residents", {
            templateUrl: "View/residents.html",
            controller: "residentsController"
        })
        .when("/rooms", {
            templateUrl: "View/rooms.html",
            controller: "apartmentsController"
        })
        .otherwise({
            template: "does not exists"
        });
});
```

// Residents Controller
(function () {

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('apartment.residentsController', ['ngResource', 'appartment.services', 'ngMaterial']);

app.controller('residentsController', function ($scope, $resource, $http, apartmentService) {

    $scope.getResidents = function () {            

        var req = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: url + '/GetResidents',
                header: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    page: $scope.page,
                    pageSize: $scope.pageSize,
                    sort: $scope.sort,
                    filter: $scope.filter,
                    orderby: $scope.orderby
                })
        };

        $scope.loading = true;
        $http(req).then(
            function (data) {
                $scope.showClientTable = true;
                $scope.residents = data.data.result;                    
                $scope.totalPages = data.data.pages;
                $scope.loading = false;
            },
            function (data) {
                console.log(data.error);
                $scope.loading = false;
            }
        );
    }

});//end controller
```

}());//end enclosure

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I was using a lot of directives that made ajax calls. For some odd reason this would cause the multiple ajax calls to happen when navigating back and forth from page to page via $routesprovider in ajax. So I removed the ajax call from the directives and placed them in functions.